# Installation of google-cloud-datastore stuck on grpcio

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing under Google Cloud Shell of Google App Engine

I am able to use datastore and all functions on 127.0.0.1 but before moving to production, I will have to install the google-cloud-datastore

I use following command:

```
pip install -t lib/ google-cloud-datastore --no-binary :all:
```

and get as below:

```
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.19.1->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-datastore)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/db/fffec68299e6d7bad3d504147f9094830b704527a7fc098b721d38cc7fa7/pyasn1-0.4.8.tar.gz
Skipping bdist_wheel for google-cloud-datastore, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for google-api-core, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for google-cloud-core, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for googleapis-common-protos, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for protobuf, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for google-auth, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for requests, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for setuptools, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for six, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for pytz, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for futures, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for grpcio, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for cachetools, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for pyasn1-modules, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for rsa, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for chardet, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for idna, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for urllib3, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for certifi, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for enum34, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Skipping bdist_wheel for pyasn1, due to binaries being disabled for it.
ipython 5.10.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.10 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: six, setuptools, protobuf, googleapis-common-protos, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, google-auth, chardet, idna, urllib3, 
certifi, requests, pytz, futures, enum34, grpcio, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-datastore
  Running setup.py install for six ... done
  Running setup.py install for setuptools ... done
  Running setup.py install for protobuf ... done
  Running setup.py install for googleapis-common-protos ... done
  Running setup.py install for cachetools ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyasn1 ... done
  Running setup.py install for pyasn1-modules ... done
  Running setup.py install for rsa ... done
  Running setup.py install for google-auth ... done
  Running setup.py install for chardet ... done
  Running setup.py install for idna ... done
  Running setup.py install for urllib3 ... done
  Running setup.py install for certifi ... done
  Running setup.py install for requests ... done
  Running setup.py install for pytz ... done
  Running setup.py install for futures ... done
  Running setup.py install for enum34 ... done
  Running setup.py install for grpcio ... /
```

The last statement **setup.py install for grpcio** is running for 25 minutes before this question post.

If I use gcloud app deploy without completion **pip install google-cloud-datastore**, I get as expected:

```
   from google.cloud import datastore
ImportError: No module named cloud"
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: `pip install -t lib/ google-cloud-datastore `

Comment: Why are you using `--no-binary :all:`?

Comment: Yes I tried `pip install -t lib/ google-cloud-datastore` and it had same issue with setup.py on install for grpcio. Using `--no-binary :all:` was to skip `bdist_wheel` in the hope it might speed up. I feel my issue is that I am on Google Cloud Shell rather than local development?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is trying to install google-cloud-datastore on Google Cloud Shell

The following worked for me:

```
sudo  apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv venv_gcd
source venv_gcd/bin/activate
pip install google-cloud-datastore
```